# Python make a list of words from a file

Tags: python, list, file

I'm trying to make a list of words from a file that includes only words that do not contain any duplicate letters such as 'hello' but 'helo' would be included.

My code words perfectly when I use a list that I create by just typing in words however when I try to do it with the file list it just prints all the words even if they include duplicate letters.

```
words = []
length = 5
file = open('dictionary.txt')
for word in file:
    if len(word) == length+1:
        words.insert(-1, word.rstrip('\n'))
alpha = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
x = 0
while x in range(0, len(alpha)):
    i = 0
    while i in range(0, len(words)):
        if words[i].count(alpha[x]) > 1:
            del(words[i])
            i = i - 1
        else:
            i = i + 1
    x = x + 1
print(words)
```

Comment: How about `def has_double_letter(word): return len(word) != len(set(word))`?

Comment: @KlausD. i want to keep the current method if possible to keep it simple, any ideas??

Comment: Then give a better error description than "does not work".

Comment: @KlausD. when i run it with a list of words that i enter this works perfectly. However when i run it this way with the file it still includes all words even if they contain duplicate letters

Comment: And now add the error description to the question by editing it.

Comment: @KlausD. Done now

Comment: Your code should actually raise an IndexError on the first double character because you remove an element of the list you are iterating over.

Comment: @KlausD. i decrement the index right after deleting it so that works fine

Comment: @KlausD. any idea what actually wrong with my code??

Comment: But that does not effect the range objects as the stop condition. And frankly, your code contains so many Python anti-patterns that it might be better to rethink it.

Comment: You shouldn't be decrementing `i`, just don't increment it in that case. Consider what happens if `i == 0` and the first word has a double letter.

Comment: This kind of bug is precisely why you should try to use higher level constructs in your homework. "But it works 100% of the time" doesn't mean it's good (readable/ maintainable/ testable/ etc.). Maybe it's homework and you're not allowed to use sets, but there are still a lot of better ways to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

What does your dictionary.txt look like? Your code should work so long as each word is on a separate line (for x in file iterates through lines) and at least some of the words have 5 non-repeating letters.

Also, couple of tips:

- You can read lines from a file into a list by calling `file.readlines()`
- You can check for repeats in a list or string by using sets. Sets remove all duplicate elements, so checking if `len(word) == len(set(word))` will tell you if there are duplicate letters in much less code :)

Comment: the text file is just a list of words all on new lines, and i know this can be done simpler but i want to keep it this way if possible... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This snippet adds words, and removes duplicated letters before inserting them

```
words = []
length = 5
file = open('dictionary.txt')
for word in file:
    clean_word = word.strip('\n')
    if len(clean_word) == length + 1:
        words.append(''.join(set(clean_word))
```

We convert the string to a set, which removed duplicates, and then we join the set to a string again:

```
>>> word = "helloool"
>>> set(word)
set(['h', 'e', 'l', 'o'])
>>> ''.join(set(word))
'helo'
```

I am not 100% sure how you want to remove duplicates like this, so I've assumed no letter can be more than once in the word (as your question specifies "duplicate letter" and not "double letter").